# Proper way to write a perfect animation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, requestanimationframe

**Current scenario:**

I have a list of `divs` which contains set of elements which scrolls automatically based on the number of `divs` present. This list of `divs` is placed inside a `parent` `div` and with fixed `height`.

**Requirements:**

- Do not animate i.e. scroll if the length of `divs` present inside is less than 4.
- Animate at same speed till the last `div` and scroll back from bottom to top vice versa.
- Stop the scroll on hover of any child `div`.

**Achieved:**

- Scrolling is done i.e. it does not scroll if less than 4 elements present.
- Scroll stops on hover of any  child `div`.
- Animate till bottom element and start from beginning.

**Problems facing at present:**

- Scrolling does not happen at same speed. It starts slowly, increases speed and ends slowly.
- After hover which stops scrolling, when it starts again, it starts slowly again.
- Once reached the end, it stays there for a few seconds and then starts from beginning.

**[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/nty6g15z/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="events_partial" class="container body-content col-md-12 col-lg-12 set-max-height">
    <div class="row sec-container" id="secContainer">
        <div style="top: -550.242px; opacity: 1;" id="secDetails">
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <p><h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3></p>
                <p>
                  Program Description which is a very long text on document and it  can be more than 2 lines
                </p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#events_partial {
    min-height: 385px !important;
    margin-top: 57px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.set-max-height {
    max-height: 385px !important;
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}

.sec-container {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#secDetails {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var animateTime = 50000; //kept varying time because as number of items increases the speed time decreased
var shouldAnimate = true;
if ($("#secDetails .container").length < 4) {
    shouldAnimate = false;
}
if ($("#secDetails .container").length >= 4 && $("#secDetails .container").length < 9)
    animateTime = 10000;
function marqueePlay() {
   if (shouldAnimate) {
       $("#secDetails").animate(
       {
            top: $("#events_partial").height() - $("#secDetails").height(),
            opacity: 1
       }, animateTime, function () {
             $("#secDetails").css("top", 1);
             $("#secDetails").css("opacity", 1);
             marqueePlay();
       });
    }
}
marqueePlay();
$("#secDetails").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(); //Stop the animation when mouse in
},
function () {
    marqueePlay(); //Start the animation when mouse out
});
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: seems like an `easing` problem. [[Link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)] & [[Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/)] should help I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have been able to understand.

***The Problem:***

- There is a default *ease* in action that you want to get rid of. The
  slow start, mid fast and slow ending in an animation is *one* of the
  different *easing* that can be applied to an animation. In your case,
  you clearly do not want it and you would want things to animate in a
  very *linear* fashion.
- There is no direct way of *resuming* a jQuery animation that I know of. So after *stopping* the animation on hover, when you call `marqueePlay()` again, it will try to animate the remaining distance in the time defined in `animateTime` variable. Distance gets reduced, but time gets re-applied. Hence, your animations seems to travel slower for a little time then gets back to normal speed. It just seems that way but in fact, it behaves exactly as it should.

***The Proposed Solution:***

- Based on my understanding above, your *linear* animation can very
  easily be achieved using `requestAnimationFrame` API.
- Avoiding `animate()` method of jQuery allows us to easily *pause* & *resume* our animations using a simple boolean flag.

Below is the snippet in action or if you are interested in viewing it as a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/jtmp43qs/).

***Snippet:***

```js
// [http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/]
window.requestAnimFrame=(function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||function(callback){window.setTimeout(callback,1000/60);};})();
var secDetails=$('#secDetails');
var container=secDetails.find('.container');
var eventsPartial=$('#events_partial');
var currTop=0;
var destTop=eventsPartial.height()-secDetails.height()-parseInt(eventsPartial.css('margin-top'));
var isPaused=false;
var isFirstLoop=true;
var speed=1;
if(container.length>=4&&container.length<9){
 requestAnimFrame(render);
 secDetails.hover(function(){isPaused=true;},function(){isPaused=false;});
 currTop=destTop;
}
function render(){
 requestAnimFrame(render);
 if(!isPaused){
  secDetails.css({transform:'translate3d(1px,'+roundDecimal(currTop,2)+'px,0px)'});
  currTop+=!isFirstLoop?-speed:speed;
  if(currTop>0) isFirstLoop=false;
  if(currTop<=destTop) currTop=0;
 }
}
function roundDecimal(value,place){ return Math.round(value*Math.pow(10,place))/Math.pow(10,place); }
```

```css
#events_partial {
 min-height: 385px !important;
 margin-top: 57px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.set-max-height {
 max-height: 385px !important;
 padding-top: 30px !important;
}
.sec-container {
 overflow: hidden !important;
 min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="events_partial" class="container body-content col-md-12 col-lg-12 set-max-height">
 <div class="row sec-container" id="secContainer">
  <div id="secDetails">
   <div class="container">
                <h3><strong> Program in Place 1 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 2 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 3 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 4 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 5 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 6 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 7 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <h3><strong> Program in Place 8 &nbsp;on&nbsp;11/22/2015</strong></h3><p>Program Description which is a very long text on document and it can be more than 2 lines</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

P.S. Although personally, I don't like the sudden jump that happens when it reaches the bottom-most and then brings the first-one into display again and starts animating again. But I can understand that it is a requirement in your scenario, perhaps it just fits to be this way. It is a taste thing. I would have had them moving up and down animating like a yoyo if I had it my way ;).

***Update:*** Here is your [**yoyo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/bqyx1mx1/1/). Also forgot to mention that you can control the speed of the animations using the `speed` variable in the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Loved this solution!! That's Bingo!! If possible can you please show sample of _animating like yoyo_ so that if I like it I'll go with it only.. :)

Comment: added an **Update** above.

Comment: Thanks alot  @Tahir. Its working fine and really this helped alot. Cheers and thanks once again for your help!! :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote 10 times to your answer!! But unfortunately not possible...

Comment: ask your friends to help you out with that ;)

Comment: Lol. Definitely not a bad idea again.. ;) anyways thanks alot once again.. :)